# Issue on custom loss function with Keras with TensorFlow backend

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to define a loss function of a three-class classification problem as the following:

```
def func_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -K.mean(K.prod(K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), K.floatx()) - 1.0, K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1), K.floatx()) - 1.0))
```

My `y` looks like this:
`[[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,0,1], ...]`

Intuitively my three-class label is a one-hot encoding of classes "-1", "0" and "+1". I want to maximize the correct labeling of "+/-1", minimize the wrong labeling of "+/-1" and ignore all "0" labels whether they are correct or not.

When I compile the model with this loss function, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 547, in compile
**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 622, in compile
sample_weight, mask)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 324, in weighted
score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "", line 2, in func_loss
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 464, in prod
axis = _normalize_axis(axis, ndim(x))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 435, in _normalize_axis
if axis is not None and axis < 0:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 547, in nonzero
raise TypeError("Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed. Use if t is not None: instead of if t: to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

I've been trying around little tweaks with this loss function but all of them results in some error when I compile the model. I think I may have some basic misunderstanding of how this thing works. Can someone help?

---

Edit: 
the new loss function:

```
def func_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -K.mean((K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), K.floatx()) - 1.0 )* (K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1), K.floatx()) - 1.0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was responding to you on the Tensorflow Github, as well.

You have edited the loss function, but you are actually getting a slightly different error now.

Before, the error was occurring the `K.mean`

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 490, in mean
axis = _normalize_axis(axis, ndim(x))
```

Now, as you can see, it is occurring in `K.prod`

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 464, in prod
axis = _normalize_axis(axis, ndim(x))
```

However, the cause is still the same: `K.mean` and `K.prod` each take one Tensor, so the second `Tensor` you are passing is being treated as the `axis` argument.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I meant to do an element-wise multiplication between `K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1) - 1` and `K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) - 1`. Can you review my new loss function? I can compile fine with this loss function but it gives me `ValueError: None values not supported`.

Comment: @TengyuLiu did you ever find a solution to this. I'm getting similar errors when using `K.argmax` in a cost function, and I believe the problem is isolated in my use of `K.argmax`.

Comment: @adalca I can't remember the exact solution but one of my mistakes at that time was that my loss function was not differentiable. If you are sure your error is isolated from syntax errors this is one direction to look at.

Comment: @TengyuLiu Thank you, I think this was my issue too -- I can compute the metric, but can't use it as a loss due to differentiation. Makes sense. I approximated the step another, differentiable, way.